# Crypt in DelphiXE7 with TDCP_rijndael AES/CBC/NoPadding algorithm and decrypt in Java

Tags: java, delphi, aes

I have a problem. I would like to crypt a text in a Delphi program and decrypt it in java. I am using AES/CBC/NoPadding to do that but the java program does not decrypt the text well.
Next step is to use a PKCS5Padding so is someone can answer this as well, it will be grat!

Delphi code:

```
var
    Cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
    Key: string;
    DataIn, DataOut: System.TArray<System.Byte>; 
begin
    Key := '0123456789012345';

    DataIn := nil;
    DataIn := TEncoding.UTF8.getbytes('SakisSakisSakisa');

    DataOut := nil;
    SetLength(DataOut, high(DataIn) + 1);
    Cipher := TDCP_rijndael.create(nil);
    Cipher.Algorithm := 'AES';
    Cipher.Init(Key[1], 128, nil);
    Cipher.EncryptCBC(DataIn[0], DataOut[0], high(DataIn) + 1);
    Cipher.Free;

    With TMemoryStream.create do begin
      Write(DataOut[0], length(DataOut));
      SaveToFile('c:\temp\encryption\sakisEnc.txt');
      Free;
    end;
```

DataIn has the following bytes:
83,97,107,105,115,83,97,107,105,115,83,97,107,105,115,97
This code produces the encryption byte array DataOut with the following bytes:
3,207,105,252,118,38,28,145,89,77,107,8,181,205,190,165

Now the Java code:

```
Path path = null;
String encryptionKey = null;
Cipher cipher = null;
SecretKeySpec key = null;
byte[] enc1;


path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("c:\\temp\\encryption\\SakisEnc.txt", "");
cipherText = Files.readAllBytes(path);

encryptionKey = "0123456789012345";   
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");   
key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(encryptionKey.getBytes()));
dec1 = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
```

The dec1 byte array should have then same bytes as with the Delphi DataIn code
83,97,107,105,115,83,97,107,105,115,83,97,107,105,115,97
but it contains something else.

I really cannot understand what i do wrong.....
Thanx in advance!

Comment: Not the problem, but use `Length(...)` rather than `high(...) + ` and use `TFileStream` to write a file rather than `TMemoryStream`.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious difference is in your key. In your Delphi code you use a UTF-16 encoded key, but in your Java code you use a UTF-8 encoded key.

In your Java code you are compelled by the library to pass bytes as the key. Unfortunately the Delphi library is more permissive and leads you into the folly of passing a string.

I would use the following for your Delphi code:

```
var
  Key: TBytes;
....
Key := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes('0123456789012345');
```

Then pass `Key[0]` to `Cipher.Init`.

Comment: But the output is different now right? Also, where in your Delphi code do you specify no padding, or is that implicit?

Comment: No padding required. The "SakisSakisSakisa" string has specifically 16 bytes.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the case. Different output means that we have at least corrected one error, encoding the key. But who knows where the other difference(s) lie.

Comment: If I were you I would attempt to encode a text that has a known output. There are plenty such examples available. That would then tell you which of your codes to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Ok after trying, reading, testing I made it work!

Delphi Code:

```
var
  Cipher: TDCP_rijndael;
  Key: System.TArray<System.Byte>;
  DataIn, DataOut, iv: System.TArray<System.Byte>; // array of byte;

  j: integer;
  i :integer;
  k :integer;
  s: string;

  sText :AnsiString;
  sTextLen :integer;
  paddingByte :string;
begin
  Key := TEncoding.UTF8.getbytes('0123456789012345');
  Iv := TEncoding.UTF8.getbytes('0123456789012345');

  DataIn := TEncoding.UTF8.getBytes(memo1.Text);
  //PKCS5Padding
  sTextLen := high(DataIn) + 1;
  i := 16 - (sTextLen mod 16);
  if i <= 16 then begin
    k := high(DataIn) + 1;
    setLength(DataIn, sTextLen + i);
    for j := k to high(DataIn) do begin
      DataIn[j] := i;
    end;
  end;

  //Encrypt.
  DataOut := nil;
  SetLength(DataOut, high(DataIn) + 1);
  Cipher := TDCP_rijndael.create(nil);
  Cipher.Algorithm := 'AES';
  Cipher.Init(Key[0], length(Key) * 8, Iv);
  Cipher.EncryptCBC(DataIn[0], DataOut[0], high(DataIn) + 1);
  Cipher.Free;

  //Save to file
  With TMemoryStream.create do begin
    Write(DataOut[0], length(DataOut));
    SaveToFile('c:\temp\encryption\sakisEnc.txt');
    Free;
  end;
```

Java Code:
In java code the delphis's Iv is the same as the encryption key. So i pass the encryptionKey to the: new IvParameterSpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"))

```
String encryptionKey = null;
Cipher cipher = null;
SecretKeySpec key = null;
byte[] enc1;
byte[] dec1;

path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("c:\\temp\\encryption\\SakisEnc.txt", "");
cipherText = Files.readAllBytes(path);

encryptionKey = "0123456789012345";
cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding") ;
key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, new IvParameterSpec(encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8")));
dec1 = cipher.doFinal(cipherText);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Decrypt(enc_Text, Pass: String): String;
var
  ciph: TCipher_Rijndael;
  APass, AIV: RawByteString;
  AData: Binary;
  i: Integer;
  AText, passBytes, passb2, iv2:TBytes;
begin
  ciph := TCipher_Rijndael.Create();
  try
    try
      AText :=TNetEncoding.Base64.DecodeStringToBytes(enc_Text);
      passBytes:=Tencoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Pass);
      passb2:=TBytes.Create(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
      for I := 0 to length(passBytes) do begin
         passb2[i]:=passBytes[i];
      end;
      iv2:=TBytes.Create(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
      for I := 0 to length(iv2) do begin
         iv2[i]:=passBytes[i];
      end;
      APass:=Binary(passb2);
      AIV:= Binary(iv2);
      ciph.Init(APass, AIV);
      Result:=ciph.DecodeBinary(Convert_RB(AText));
    finally
      ciph.Free;
      ProtectBinary(AData);
      ProtectBinary(APass);
    end;
  except
    Result := '';
  end;
end;
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.